# jQuery datatables refresh data not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

i can use server side to fill datatables and other working that but i cant refresh data after clicking on `reload_table` element.clear datatable is work correctly but draw not working.

JQUERY:

```
$('#reload_table').live('click',function(){
   oTable_topics.fnReloadAjax(oTable_topics.fnSettings());
   oTable_topics.fnClearTable();
   oTable_topics.fnDraw();
    $.ajax({
       url: "server_processing.php",
       success: function() {
           // if it worked, ask datatable to redraw the table with the new data
           $("#showTopics").dataTable().fnDraw();
           // if this js function does anything useful (like deleting the row), then call it:
           Success();
       },
       error: function() {
           // display any error (like server couldn't be reached...), or at least try to log it
       }
    });
});
oTable_topics =$('#showTopics').dataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 12,                               
        "bScrollCollapse": true,       
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,

        "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
            clickRowHandler_topics();
            if ( oSettings.aiDisplay.length == 0 )
            {
                return;
            }                       
            var nTrs = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);
            var iColspan = nTrs[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
            var sLastGroup = "";
            for ( var i=0 ; i<nTrs.length ; i++ )
            {
                var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
                var sGroup = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex] ]._aData[0];
                if ( sGroup != sLastGroup )
                {
                    var nGroup = document.createElement( 'tr' );
                    var nCell = document.createElement( 'td' );
                    nCell.colSpan = iColspan;
                    nCell.className = "group";
                    nCell.innerHTML = sGroup;
                    nGroup.appendChild( nCell );
                    nTrs[i].parentNode.insertBefore( nGroup, nTrs[i] );
                    sLastGroup = sGroup;
                }
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
        "aaSortingFixed": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
          aoData.push(
             {"name": "id"   ,      "value": "i.id" },          
             {"name": "subject"   , "value": "i.subject" },
             {"name": "date_time",  "value": "i.date_time"} ,
             {"name": "posted_by",  "value": "u.username"} ,
             {"name": "ctitle"   ,  "value": "c.title"} ,
             {"name": "etitle"   ,  "value": "e.title"},
             {"name": "istatus"   ,  "value": "i.status"},
             {"name": "join"     ,  "value": "JOIN categories c ON i.category = c.id JOIN status_topics e ON i.status = e.id JOIN users u ON i.posted_by = c.id"},
             {"name": "action"   ,  "value": "topics" }
          )}
        });
```

Comment: .live has been deprecated please use on

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam, yes but my problem is redraw table.

Comment: mahdi, maybe you should try to ask also on http://datatables.net/forums/

Comment: Allan's fnReloadAjax says "By default DataTables only uses the sAjaxSource variable at initialisation time, however it can be useful to re-read an Ajax source and have the table update. Typically you would need to use the fnClearTable() and fnAddData() functions, however this wraps it all up in a single function call."  His example only shows calling fnReloadAjax.  I don't think you need to call fnClearTable.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using fnReloadAjax to load new data and fnLengthChange to change the page length while I am at it.

```
oTable.fnClearTable(0);
oTable.fnReloadAjax('/' + myLocation + '/' + myCustomerId);
oTable.fnLengthChange(pageLength);
```